# Will I break the inversion of control principle if I use andersao/l5-repository in my Laravel 5 project?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, inversion-of-control

I am novice Laravel developer and I am trying to understand and apply the `SOLID` principles like a good programmer. So I recently learnt and applied the repository pattern in laravel.

To do this, I created a directory archive and loaded it with `psr-4` like so:

```
"Archive\\": "archive/"
```

Then I created a folder called `Repositories` and another in it called `Contracts`. Now in the Contracts folder I have `interfaces` like `UserRepositoryInterface` and `ServicesRepositoryInterface` and so on, and outside in the `Repositories` folder, I have implementation like `DbUserRepository` and `DbServiceRepository` and so on.

I am using a `service provider` called `DataServiceProvider` where I bind these like so:

```
$this->app->bind(UserRepositoryInterface::class, DbUserRepository::class);
$this->app->bind(ServiceRepositoryInterface::class, DbServiceRepository::class);
```

So this way I can inject the `Contacts` like `UserRepositoryInterface` and `ServiceRepositoryInterface` in my controllers and Laravel automatically resolves my dependencies out of the IoC container. So if in the future I need a `FileUserRepository`, I just need to create that class and change the binding in my `service provider` and nothing will break in my controllers.

This is what I have learnt from Taylor and Jeffrey. But now I am trying to use a package https://github.com/andersao/l5-repository for my project.

According to this, I will `extend` my `DbUserRepository` with the BaseRepository which comes with it like so:

```
namespace App;

use Prettus\Repository\Eloquent\BaseRepository;

class UserRepository extends BaseRepository {

    /**
     * Specify Model class name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function model()
    {
        return "App\\Post";
    }
}
```

Now in this I am obviously reusing all the code and power that comes with the `BaseRepository` like `all()`, `panginate($limit = null, $columns = ['*'])`, `find($id)` and so on but now am I breaking the Inversion of Control Principle because now I will have to inject concrete implementations into my controller?

I am still a novice developer and trying to understand all this and may have gone wrong somewhere in the question when explaining things. What is the best way to go around using the package while also maintaining a loose coupling in the controllers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason why you still can't implement your interface:

```
namespace App;

use Prettus\Repository\Eloquent\BaseRepository;

class DbUserRepository extends BaseRepository implements UserRepositoryInterface {

    /**
     * Specify Model class name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    function model()
    {
        return "App\\Post";
    }
}
```

However, you are now faced with a problem; if you swap out your implementation, there is nothing in your `UserRepositoryInterface` to say that the `BaseRepository` methods must also be implemented. If you take a look at the `BaseRepository` class, you should see that it implements two interfaces of it's own: `RepositoryInterface` and `RepositoryCriteriaInterface` and 'luckily' php allows for `multiple interface inheritence` which means you can extend your `UserRepositoryInterface` as follows:

```
interface UserRepositoryInterface extends RepositoryInterface, RepositoryCriteriaInterface {

  // Declare UserRepositoryInterface methods

}
```

and you can then bind and use your interface as normal:

`$this->app->bind(UserRepositoryInterface::class, DbUserRepository::class);`

Comment: Ah, I realized later that the class `extends` the `BaseRepository` but then implements a contract too.